Geometric Brownian motion simulations computed in different ways
I have come across three different equations that, as far as I know, will yield the same Geometric Brownian Motion process given that we use the same random variables in each case; however, when I try to convince myself that this is true by computing the resulting processes in R, I can only get two of the three to output the expected GBM, and the third is only just slightly off.
The three equations I'm using are:
$$\Delta S_t = \mu S_t \Delta t + \sigma \sqrt{\Delta t}Z S_t$$
$$S_t = S_0 e^{(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t+\sigma \sqrt{\Delta t} W_t}$$
$$\Delta S_t = S_{t} e^{(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})\Delta t+\sigma \sqrt{\Delta t}Z}$$
Where $Z$ is a standard normal random variable, $W_t$ is the Wiener process, and I'm using $\Delta t$ and $\Delta S$ instead of $dt$ and $dS$ because my time steps are large.
My R code and the output for the code are below. I'm trying to figure out why the latter two methods produce the same result but the former is off slightly. Could someone please help find the error in my code or let me know where my understanding is flawed?
Z <- rnorm(12, mean=0, sd=1)

# the resulting wiener process
W <- cumsum(Z)

# initialize parameters
mu <- 0.1
sig <- 0.2
S0 <- 10

#dS=mu*S*dt+sig*S*dW definition of gbm
sim1 <- c(S0)
for (n in 1:length(Z)){
  dS <- (1/12)*mu*sim1[n]+sqrt(1/12)*sig*sim1[n]*Z[n]
  sim1 <- append(sim1, sim1[n]+dS)
}

# exponential analytic solution 
sim2 <- c(S0)
t <- 0
for (n in 1:length(Z)){
  t <- t+(1/12)
  sim2 <- append(sim2, S0*exp((mu-sig*sig*0.5)*t+sqrt(1/12)*sig*W[n]))
}

# incremental exponential solution
sim3 <- c(S0)
for (n in 1:length(Z)){
  sim3 <- append(sim3, sim3[n]* exp((mu - sig * sig / 2) * (1/12) 
                       + sig * Z[n] * sqrt(1/12)))
}

Output
 [1] 10.000000  9.471675 10.268718 11.624626 11.168953 11.338817 11.053753 10.191896
 [9] 10.380249 11.328181 12.042882 11.459601 11.555696

 [1] 10.000000  9.469593 10.283796 11.715882 11.246756 11.400095 11.098550 10.248980
 [9] 10.422763 11.400374 12.122583 11.530201 11.607932

 [1] 10.000000  9.469593 10.283796 11.715882 11.246756 11.400095 11.098550 10.248980
 [9] 10.422763 11.400374 12.122583 11.530201 11.607932


The first expression does not represent the exact distribution of the increment. It is a so called Euler approximation of the increment.

@JesperTidblom You are correct. Increasing the number of time steps converges the first expression towards the expected result. Thanks
